# Show that $x-\frac{x^{2}\sin x}{(1+nx^{2})(1+(n-1)x^{2})}$ can be simplified to $\frac{|\sin x|}{1+nx^{2}}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, convergence-divergence, continuity, uniform-convergence

I was doing a problem on uniform convergence. The book wishes to prove $$\frac{x^{2}\sin x}{(1+nx^{2})(1+(n-1)x^{2})}$$ uniformly converges to $x$. The first inequality is derived from the book's use of the definition of uniform convergence, which is to set $S(x) - S_{n}(x) < \epsilon$. In doing so, my book just skipped from

$$x-\frac{x^{2}\sin x}{(1+nx^{2})(1+(n-1)x^{2})}$$ to this $$\frac{|\sin x|}{1+nx^{2}}$$

I have no idea how that came about. Does anyone have any idea? I've tried basic variable manipulation, but I couldn't get anything substantial out of that denominator.

(since I don't know how this is done, I put a couple tags that may turn out to be extraneous)

Comment: What does the book claim is the relationship between the two? Because they are certainly not equal. (Consider $x=\pi$ for example. The LHS is then $\pi$ while the RHS is $0$)

Comment: The book merely says that the first equation can also be described as the second equation. And then it moves on to show uniform convergence.

Comment: For what sequence of functions is the uniform convergence being investigated? We don't know what book you are using, what the problem is that you are working on, or anything like that. We just know that at some point in the argument, it is claimed that one expression is somehow related to another. It is fairly difficult to answer without some more context.

Comment: I didn't include it because I didn't think the uniform convergence aspect was truly relevant to the problem; the book I'm using simply gives me that conclusion as well.

But here it is:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2}sinx}{(1+nx^{2})(1+(n-1)x^{2})}$$

The example illustrates how that uniformly converges to $x$. However, like I said in the main question, it makes the leap between those two equalities.

Comment: That converges to $\sin x$, not to $x$. I think I know where the $\frac{|\sin x|}{1+nx^2}$ comes from though. (But not where the other quantity comes from. So I'm not sure if I can provide an answer about the link between the two.)

Comment: The way the book describes uniform convergence, it says that the best way to apply the definition is by setting $$|S(x) -S_{n}(x)|$$ less than epsilon. Which is how the first inequality is derived.

Again, I'm sorry for not providing this context earlier. I thought the issue was that I could not get between the two equations I posted in the original post, so I didn't elaborate on the uniform convergence aspect because I thought it was extraneous.


If you could show how it converges to $sin(x)$, maybe that will help. This book has been wrong before.

Comment: Don't worry. You can edit the details in if you want. (There should be a link to edit your question below the question.) I apologise if I came across too strongly or severely. I am still not entirely sure what the book is doing (not your fault; you have provided a bit of context now) I think that there may be an error in the book though, because the series converges to $\sin x$ and not to $x$. I'll type up an answer that gets as far as showing the relevance of $\frac{|\sin x|}{1+nx^2}$. Hopefully it will be useful.

Comment: On a completely unrelated note, $\sin x$ looks nicer in $\LaTeX$ if you use \sin instead of sin.

Answer (score 0):

To find the value of the series
$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^2 \sin x}{(1+nx^2)(1+(n-1)x^2)}$$
it will help to find an expression for the partial sums, and then find what the limit of the partial sums are. (And the issue of uniform convergence is then asking if the partial sums converge uniformly)

On way of doing this is to use partial fractions to decompose
$$ \frac{x^2}{(1+nx^2)(1+(n-1)x^2)}$$
into partial fractions. This often allows one to write the sum as a telescoping series, which is easy to evaluate.

In this case, one finds that
$$\frac{x^2 \sin x}{(1+nx^2)(1+(n-1)x^2)} = \frac{1}{1+(n-1)x^2}-\frac{1}{1+nx^2}$$

The original sum is then
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{\sin x}{1+(n-1)x^2}-\frac{\sin x}{1+nx^2}\right)$$

and the partial sums are
$$ S_n(x) = \sum_{k=1}^n \left(\frac{\sin x}{1+(k-1)x^2}-\frac{\sin x}{1+kx^2}\right)$$

Most of the terms cancel, and we are left with just
$$ S_n(x) = \sin x - \frac{\sin x}{1+nx^2} $$

For a fixed $x$, it is not too difficult to see that
$$ S_n(x) \to \sin x \text{ as } n \to \infty $$
so the pointwise limit of the series is $S(x) = \sin x$

To investigate the uniform convergence, we consider the quantity
$$ |S(x) - S_n(x)| $$
which is equal to
$$ \left|\sin x - \sin x + \frac{\sin x}{1+nx^2} \right| = \frac{|\sin x|}{1+nx^2} $$

The original series will converge uniformly to $\sin x$ provided that this quantity converges uniformly to $0$.

I don't know where the quantity
$$x - \frac{x^2 \sin x}{(1+nx^2)(1+(n-1)x^2)}$$
comes from though. It might be because the book erroneously starts off by asserting that the series converges to $x$ instead of $\sin x$. It should instead be considering the quantity
$$\sin x - \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{x^2 \sin x}{(1+nx^2)(1+(n-1)x^2)}$$
which *is* equal to
$$ \frac{\sin x}{1+nx^2} $$
as shown above.